# How to run multiple copies of a program?

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines

I need to run a scientific program. One can usually only run one copy of it at any one time, it wont allow another copy to be open at the same time (somehow).

I would like to set up virtual servers or similar to run multiple instances of this resource intensive program and be able to seamlessly switch between these instances.

What would be the best way to do that? I would prefer to do this on a mac but linux or windows are options.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, we do not teach you RTFM for virtualiaztion sotware and system administration here.

Comment: Sorry I didnt know.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Chaoxiang, containerize it.
Docker is also available for Mac so that's a way. For linux there's docker, kubernetes, lxc. Windows has docker as well but I'm not sure how well that works. You should be able to use the windows Sandbox too but then all data is gone once you shut it down and that may not be what you want.

So, more than enough choices but they all involve containers.

One question though; 'why' do you want to tun it multiple times? If it's that resource intensive then you probably shouldn't run more than 1. Everything will just take a lot longer to finish, maybe even longer than when you would run them after eachother.

Comment: I set up the calculations on my workstation and then run the job or the actual calculations remotely.I want to perform several runs simultaneously to work on different projects at the same time since it just takes so long for one run to finish, sometimes 2 hours or more and you cant do anything in the mean time.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be, to containerize your application and use a container orchestrator to simply run multiple instances of your application at a same time.

Given sufficien ressources, this would solve the instance problem.